# Spring SchedulingConfigurer dynamic delay

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I have an app that should do something once everyday between between 7am and 7pm. I want to randomly pick a valid time to run the task, then use a DIFFERENT start time for the *next* task.

Every solution I've found generates a valid random start cron, but then its the same cron for each run afterwards. I need a different, random start each time.

I tried using a CronTrigger, but that still ends up being constant. Here's some example code:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(this.taskExecutor());
    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
      () -> logger.info("The time is {}", dateFormat.format(new Date())),
      new CronTrigger(this.randomCron(0, 60)));
  }

  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
  }

  private String randomCron(int min, int max) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max) + " * * * * *";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned about [Triggers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html) in Spring which you can use to schedule your next run. My new code looks like this now:

```
  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(this.taskExecutor());
    taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
      () -> logger.info("The time is {}", dateFormat.format(new Date())),
      (tc) -> {
        Date lastCompletion = tc.lastCompletionTime();
        if (lastCompletion == null) {
          lastCompletion = new Date();
        }
        Calendar cal = new Calendar.Builder().setInstant(lastCompletion).build();
        int second = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 60);
        long minute = 60000L + second * 1000L;
        Date nextRun = new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() + minute);
        logger.info("Next run will be at {}", nextRun);
        logger.info("Time between runs is {}", minute);
        return new Date();
      });
  }
```